# Making the console Print() the user's inputs in order?

Tags: java

```
public class PlayerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Ask how many players will play
        System.out.print("How many players(4 max) : ");
        int value = input.nextInt();

        while (true) {
            /* Players need to be 1-4 max */
            if (value <= 4 && value >= 1) {
                System.out.println("You have " + value + " players");
                break;
                /* Cannot be less than 1 */
            } else if (value < 1) {
                System.out.println("(You cannot have less than 1 player)");
                System.out.println("Please Try again : ");
                value = input.nextInt();
                /* Cannot be more than 4 */
            } else if (value > 4) {
                System.out.println("(You cannot have more than 4 players)");
                System.out.println("Please try again :");
                value = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
            System.out.println("Player" + i + " Please Enter your name : ");
            String PlayerName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your number : ");
            int PlayerNumber = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(PlayerName);
        System.out.println(PlayerNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

If the user wants to put `2` players in the game, it will ask them to input their `Name` and `Number`. After entering their values, I'd like the console to output **Player 1's** `Name` and `Number` and then **Player 2's** `Name` and `Number`.

***Exemple of what I want***

```
John 30
Robert 50
```

Comment: Okay! so what is the problem?

Comment: Which part of what you've written makes you expect to get all of them out? Yes, I'm being your rubber duck right now.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm very new to Java and was hoping I'd get some help on how this would be achieved?

Comment: This works for me, the player's name and number are printed right after you ask for them. Then it asks for the next player name and number, and it prints the new values, etc. But they are all printed

Comment: @Crypto have you considered using an object-oriented approach of making a class Player with two fields for the player's name and age. Could easily be done similar as in the [Java Tutorial on classes/objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), then you could reference each player individually and get each name/age. or add players to a list, etc.

Comment: @downshift I'll try. I have to learn a bit more I guess to do more complex stuff. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Crypto, welcome, there are many ways to accomplish what you were trying to do, use simple arrays, hashmaps, etc. that was just one suggestion. I'm glad you found a good answer. :)

Comment: There's so many interesting things to learn oh gosh. I'll try my best to enhance my knowledge and become a better programmer. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to provide an answer to the question.  Keep in mind I am also a very new beginner.  However, the following does what I *think* you need as you were not very specific. I am using a very basic class as @downshift recommended.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomClass
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        int num;

        PlayerInfo[] players = new PlayerInfo[4];

        // Ask how many players will play
        System.out.print("How many players(4 max) : ");
        int value = input.nextInt();

        while (true) 
        {
            // Players need to be 1-4 max
            if (value <= 4 && value >= 1) {
                System.out.println("You have " + value + " players");
                break;
                // Cannot be less than 1
            } else if (value < 1) {
                System.out.println("(You cannot have less than 1 player)");
                System.out.println("Please Try again : ");
                value = input.nextInt();
                // Cannot be more than 4
            } else if (value > 4) {
                System.out.println("(You cannot have more than 4 players)");
                System.out.println("Please try again :");
                value = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Player" + (i + 1) + " Please Enter your name : ");
            String PlayerName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your number : ");
            int PlayerNumber = input.nextInt();

            players[i] = new PlayerInfo(PlayerName, PlayerNumber);

        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(players[i].getName());
            System.out.println(players[i].getNum());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class PlayerInfo
{
    // variables
    private String name;
    private int num;

    // constructors
    public PlayerInfo() {}

    public PlayerInfo (String xname, int xnum)
    {
        name = xname;
        num = xnum;
    }

    // methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's some issues with your code :S there's duplicate variables but I get your point. I just need to learn how to use instructors and get a better understanding on arrays. Thanks for the help :)